# Float: Right IE7 Bug

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css-float, internet-explorer-6

I can't figure out IE7 float right bug!  This is killing me.  My NAV bar looks great everywhere except IE7.  I already created a specific IE7 CSS and have tried various approaches, but still no success.
[link text](http://www.ubspack.com)

It appears the `LI` elements are floating outside the `#NAV` inside the .container.

Anyone of a IE7 fix for `FLOAT:RIGHT`?

Many thanks.

Here is my code:

```
.container {
    width: 983px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: fuchsia;
}
ul#nav {
    height: 44px;
    margin: 32px auto;
    position: relative;
}
ul#nav li, ul#nav li a {
    display: block;
    height: 44px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    position: relative;
}
ul#nav li {
    padding-left: 0;
    height: 44px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10060;
}


<div class="container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a class="navtop_7" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="navtop_6" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="navtop_5" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="navtop_4" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="navtop_3" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="navtop_2" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="navtop_1" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [jsfiddle.net example](http://jsfiddle.net/XLnYJ/1/) displays in IE7 the way I *think* you want it to, based on your description. (For future reference, supply a reference image you are trying to achieve.)

```
.container {
    width: 983px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: fuchsia;
}
ul#nav {
    height: 44px;
    margin: 32px auto;
}
ul#nav li {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    background: green;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 140px
    height: 44px;
}
ul#nav li a {
    background: blue;
    display: block;
    height: 44px;
    width: 137px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```